# NHibernate.MappingException no mapping for that class exists

Tags: c#

Here is the nHibernate Mapping .I can not catch the problem

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="DSEBO.Data" assembly="DSEBO.Data ">


 <class name="CommissionAgent" table="CommissionAgent">  
  <id name="Id" column="Id" type="integer">
    <generator class="increment"></generator>
  </id>     
  <property name="CommissionAgentName" type="String" column="AgentName" length="50"/>
  <property name="CommissionAgentCode" type="String" column="AgentCode" length="50"/>
</class>
```

Here is The Class:

```
 public class CommissionAgent
{
    private int id { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string commissionAgentName { get; set; }

    public virtual string CommissionAgentName
    {
        get { return commissionAgentName; }
        set { commissionAgentName = value; }
    }
        }
```

1. I have getting the exception
2. No mapping found

Comment: And which class are you trying to map? Is it `CommissionAgent` ? Isn't there a chance that You are calling mapping on some other class in the code?

Comment: Class has been added ,You can check this now

Comment: Please re-read last sentence I wrote: Isn't there a chance that you are calling mapping on some other class(es) in the code? Are you mapping only this `CommissionAgent ` class or are there more classes? In that case you would need to enter more mappings in that configuration file.